# How to implement autoclosing '$' signs for LaTeX similar to that of parentheses in vim

Tags: vim, latex

I want to find a way of achieving the autocompleting functionality that the vim plugin DelimitMate provides for parentheses but instead for dollar signs. For example, typing `$` should yield `$$` with the cursor in-between both characters. Moreover, after typing said text within the dollar signs, e.g. `$math stuff here$`, typing `$` again should move my cursor out of the in-line math block. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use the delimitMate plugin, but according to [its documentation](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate/blob/master/doc/delimitMate.txt), you should be able to configure the `$` as additional *quotes*:

```
au FileType tex let b:delimitMate_quotes = "\" ' $"
```

(Or alternatively put the `:let` command into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`.